# How to prove that $V=\left\{\left(2x-1,x\right)\vert x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ is not a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How to prove that $$V=\left\{\left(2x-1,x\right)\vert x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$$ is not a vector space?

Comment: It is not a vector subpace of $\mathbf R^, but is a *affine* subspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vector spaces are closed under vector addition and scalar multiplication. With $V=\left\{\left(2x-1,x\right)\vert x \in \mathbb{R}\right\}$ we can put $x = 1$ and then $(1, 1) \in V$. But multiply this by $2$ and then $2.(1, 1) =(2, 2) \not \in V$. You can have $(3, 2) $ and $(2, 3/2) \in V$, but not $(2, 2)$

So, $V$ is not algebraically closed and therefore not a vector space.

Answer (score 6):

**Hint**: the zero vector is not in $V$ (*Why? What does this imply?*).

Answer (score 2):

Is there an $x \in \mathbb{R}$ that would make $(2x -1, x ) = (0,0)$? well, we would have

$$ x = \frac{1}{2} \; \; \text{and} \; \; x = 0 $$

which is impossible